# Collapsing levels of a variable by another variable with certain conditions

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following example data table:

```
library(data.table)
exdt <- structure(list(domain = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                          2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                          2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                          2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
                       L1 = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
                              10L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 
                              18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
                              25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L), 
                       L2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
                              7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 
                              11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
                              14L, 14L)), 
                  row.names = c(NA, -51L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

I'd like to create a new variable `L2`, which is a grouping of two **consecutive**, **unique** levels of `L1` within levels of `domain`. However, when I get to the end of a `domain`, I sometimes have a level of `L1` that is stand-alone. In that case, I'd like to merge it with the two unique levels before it. This means  that at the end of a domain, I may have merged together 3 consecutive, unique levels of `L1` instead of 2 unique levels. The desired output is shown below.

```
exdt_L2_desired <- structure(list(domain = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
                                  L1 = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
                                         10L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 
                                         18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
                                         25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L), 
                                  L2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L,3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
                                         6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 
                                         11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L)), row.names = c(NA, -51L), 
                             class = c("data.table","data.frame"))

 domain L1 L2
      1  1  1
      1  1  1
      1  2  1
      1  2  1
      1  3  1
      1  3  1
      2  4  2
      2  4  2
      2  5  2
      2  5  2
      2  5  2
      2  5  2
      2  6  3
      2  7  3
      2  8  4
      2  8  4
      2  9  4
      2  9  4
      2 10  5
      2 10  5
      2 11  5
      2 12  6
      2 12  6
      2 13  6
      2 13  6
      2 14  7
      2 15  7
      2 15  7
      2 16  8
      2 16  8
      2 17  8
      2 17  8
      2 18  9
      2 18  9
      2 19  9
      2 19  9
      2 20 10
      2 21 10
      2 22 11
      2 22 11
      2 23 11
      2 23 11
      2 23 11
      2 24 12
      2 25 12
      2 25 12
      2 25 12
      2 25 12
      2 26 12
      2 26 12
      2 26 12
```

You can check that this has the right grouping `L2` by:

```
#Check
exdt_L2_desired[, .(numL1_lev = uniqueN(L1)), by = list(domain,L2)]

    domain L2 numL1_lev
 1:      1  1         3
 2:      2  2         2
 3:      2  3         2
 4:      2  4         2
 5:      2  5         2
 6:      2  6         2
 7:      2  7         2
 8:      2  8         2
 9:      2  9         2
10:      2 10         2
11:      2 11         2
12:      2 12         3
```

As you can see each level of `L2` has 2 or 3 levels of `L1`. For `domain=1`, `numL1_lev=3` because there were only 3 unique `L1` values, which were lumped into a single group. For `domain=2`, only the last level of `L2` had the `numL1_lev=3`.

**Attempt**

I tried the following, but I seem to still have trouble getting the stand-alone levels of `L1` within a given domain:

```
exdt_L2 <- exdt[, L2 := 
                  exdt[, {x <- ceiling(L1/2)  #Group 2 consecutive, unique L1 levels by domain
                  #If the number of unique L1 levels at the end is stand-alone, then replace with previous group
                     if (length(unique(L1[x==x[.N]])) == 1) x[x==x[.N]] <- x[.N]-1
                     x
                     }, domain][, rleid(domain, V1)]
                   ]

 domain L1 L2
      1  1  1
      1  1  1
      1  2  1
      1  2  1
      1  3  1
      1  3  1
      2  4  2
      2  4  2
      2  5  3
      2  5  3
      2  5  3
      2  5  3
      2  6  3
      2  7  4
      2  8  4
      2  8  4
      2  9  5
      2  9  5
      2 10  5
      2 10  5
      2 11  6
      2 12  6
      2 12  6
      2 13  7
      2 13  7
      2 14  7
      2 15  8
      2 15  8
      2 16  8
      2 16  8
      2 17  9
      2 17  9
      2 18  9
      2 18  9
      2 19 10
      2 19 10
      2 20 10
      2 21 11
      2 22 11
      2 22 11
      2 23 12
      2 23 12
      2 23 12
      2 24 12
      2 25 13
      2 25 13
      2 25 13
      2 25 13
      2 26 13
      2 26 13
      2 26 13
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using just `ceiling(L1 / 2)` will not work, as this assigns e.g. `L1 = 4` and `L1 = 5` to different bins, which should be added to the same `L2` bin. Below is an updated version in the same spirit as OP's attempt instead using `ceiling(rleid(L1) / 2)`:

```r
library(data.table)

exdt[, L2 := {
      ## modify rle values
      x <- ceiling(rleid(L1) / 2)
      n <- length(unique(L1))
      ## if n is odd update last bin values
      if(n > 1 && n %% 2 == 1) {
        x[x == x[.N]] <- x[.N] - 1
      }
      x
    }, by = "domain"][, L2 := rleid(domain, L2)]

all.equal(exdt, exdt_L2_desired)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain the "[, L2 := rleid(domain, L2)]" part?

Comment: In the first assignment `L2` starts from 1 in each domain group (due to the definition of `x` based on `rleid`). The second assignment then updates the `L2` column to continue counting across domain groups (check the output of `L2` when the `[, L2 := rleid(domain, L2)]` part is not included)

Comment: Ah got it. Thanks!